# jquery image slider with curtain effect

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking for a jQuery image slider with a special curtain effect.

Images should be crossfaded by dividing the active image into two parts in center and slide the left part to the left and the right one to the right.
So the effect simulates drawing a curtain e.g. in theatre.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use jQuery Cycle. It's a fantastic plugin.

Have a look on the effects browser (at the curtain ones).

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

If you don't like any of them you can build your own effects.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv2.html

Comment: If you do build your own transition add it to the question so we can see how you got on.

Answer (score 1):

I have created this one http://jsbin.com/akarow/2 more or less as a proof of concept. I did not find a specific plug-in with this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found something similar with the one you're asking, but this [website here](http://www.queness.com/post/10497/8-jquery-image-sliders-with-impressive-transition-effects), offers some pretty nice ones. Check them out and some of them have similar techniques.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there is one that looks pretty similar